# WordPress theme development ||| Directory theme name

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, directory, wordpress-theming

I have created my own theme from scratch. I am therefore in the process of testing the theme through the plugin **Theme Check**.

> "WARNING: Your theme appears to be in the wrong directory for the theme name.
>   The directory name must match the slug of the theme. This theme's
>   correct slug and text-domain is twentyeleven.”

The name is just an example.

I can’t change the name of the folder, without the theme losing a lot of elements on the page. I reinstall the theme each time. It also does not work when I change the name in style.css.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: if you declare any text domain then please match it

Comment: you cant really rename the plugin/theme folders for installed plugins and themes, or if you do change the wp_option value for installed plugins or active theme.

Answer (score 1):

Submit your template on http://themecheck.org they will give you proper slug text-domain for your theme name. Kindly check Text Domain: in style.css also.

Answer (score 0):

Now on **5.09.2019** I have faced the same problem. In my case making the text-domain and the theme folder name 100% the same & remember that it is case sensitive.

Example: `wp-content/themes/khaowadaowa`

Then your text-domain must be `* Text Domain: khaowadaowa`